# Use ZF2 Modules for non-Site cronJob

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Is there a way to use my ZF2 modules (DB-Models specifically) in a PHP-Cronscript that is independent of the site itself? How exactly has it to look like?

Comment: Have you checked the [console docs](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.console.introduction.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I already do this by using the Console directives. You'll be able to do something like:

```
php public/index.php cron diskspace_update
```

I actually have many crons running this way and so far so good. They also interact with a DB